# Como sacar el Actionbar de una SplashScreen

Tags: java, android-studio

Sólo necesito como hacer desaparecer la barra superior al momento que se inicia la app con una imagen que puse.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma de crear el splash seria:

1: Crear un recurso splash.xml en la carpeta drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/inicioimg"/>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

2. Crear un activity (SplashActivity)sin layout en el cual definas donde quieres ir despues de cargar tu splas.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
 }
}
```

3. en tu Manifest decir que vas a iniciar con esa pantalla:

```html
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreen">
            
</activity>
```

4. puedes sobre escribir la clase Application
   para decirle el tiempo que tardare en el splash

   SystemClock.sleep(2000);